# Can stripes:select return an object of inner collection?

Tags: jsp, select, user-interface, stripes

Please help me with stripes:select component. I want something like this:

```
   <stripes:select name="teachers[${loop.index}].school" value="${item.school}">
     <stripes:options-collection collection="${actionBean.schools}" label="name" value="${this}"/>
   </stripes:select>
```

Of course, you can't do value="${this}" in options-collection. But, how should I specify that I want to return school not by id, but school itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Stripes handles type conversion for nested properties. Assuming Teacher has a property of type School, Stripes will automatically do the type conversion for you.

```
<stripes:select name="teachers[${loop.index}].school">
    <stripes:options-collection collection="${actionBean.schools}" value="id" label="name"/>
</stripes:select>
```

teachers[i].school will be a School, not just an id String.

See http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Indexed+Properties for an excellent explanation.